# SQL Query for calculating current balance from opening

Tags: mysql, sql

I need you help me to make a sql query for balance calculation.
Please check out my table below. "opening" only used for the first time for calculation.

Thanks very much

Here is my table

```
trx_no  Opening  debit  credit
ab123   200      0      100
ab456   200      0      50
ab789   200      0      50
cd123   200      50     0
cd456   200      0      10
cd789   200      0      40
```

Here is the expected result

```
trx_no  Opening  debit  credit    balance
ab123   200      0      100       300
ab456   200      0      50        350 
ab789   200      0      50        400
cd123   200      50     0         350
cd456   200      0      10        360
cd789   200      0      40        400
```

Comment: indeed @TimBiegeleisen just noticed it was a rolling sum just before your comment..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your `trx_no` column would *always* be a fixed width of 5 characters, and that lexicographical sorting indicates the age of the transaction, then we can try using a correlated subquery here to find the rolling balance:

```
SELECT
    trx_no,
    Opening,
    debit,
    credit,
    Opening + (SELECT SUM(t2.credit - t2.debit)
               FROM yourTable t2
               WHERE t2.trx_no <= t1.trx_no) AS balance
FROM yourTable t1
ORDER BY
    trx_no;
```

If you are using MySQL 8+, then window functions make this a bit less verbose:

```
SELECT
    trx_no,
    Opening,
    debit,
    credit,
    Opening +
        SUM(credit - debit) OVER (OVER ORDER BY trx_no) AS balance
FROM yourTable t1
ORDER BY
    trx_no;
```

Comment: @RaymondNijland No, your comment was valid, but I explained it at least one way.  If the OP doesn't have a good column to order the transactions, then all bets are off for any answer ^ ^

Comment: indeed Tim you are right.. @JavMad assuming the lexicographical sorting indicates the age of the transaction like Tim is assuming but not always a fixed width of 5 characters here you would try `ORDER BY   
     HEX(REPLACE(trx_no, REVERSE(REVERSE(trx_no) >> 0), ''))
   , HEX(REPLACE(trx_no, REVERSE(REVERSE(trx_no) >> 0), '')) + REVERSE(REVERSE(trx_no) >> 0) ` -> see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ub9hrv9gc3XuRbRCgqTqdW/1) in combination with these queries..

Comment: `ROWS BETWEEN` is not needed.  The `ORDER BY` is sufficient.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I almost never use the advanced window function syntax.  I relied my answer on some documentations which perhaps were writing out the range explicitly for didactic purposes.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . I think it is required in Teradata.  Otherwise, it looks unnecessarily cumbersome -- and I think confuses new people who are learning window functions.

Comment: wouldn't adding the balance line by line be a bottleneck in performance? Wouldn't there be a more efficient way to do this, for example, get the balance initially and then add the balance to the current value?

Comment: @Marcoscdoni Yes, and the second query in my answer is doing precisely this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Are you sure about that statement? I did a comparative test between the second query and one I used using CTE and apparently paid large data sets using CTE was significantly faster.

Answer (score 0):

One more question, how about the query to get the last balance with a single query?
Thank you

```
trx_no  Opening  debit  credit    balance lastbalance
ab123   200      0      100       300     400
ab456   200      0      50        350     400
ab789   200      0      50        400     400
cd123   200      50     0         350     400
cd456   200      0      10        360     400
cd789   200      0      40        400     400
```

Edit:
I use this query, I got the correct result but I am not sure that this query is right (good) or not :

SELECT trx_no, Opening, debit, credit, Opening + (SELECT SUM(t2.credit - t2.debit) FROM yourTable t2 WHERE t2.trx_no <= t1.trx_no) AS balance, Opening + (SELECT SUM(credit - debit) FROM yourTable ) AS lastbalance FROM yourTable t1 ORDER BY trx_no;